# Add UIImage at End of PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiimage

I used Apple's documentation to create a Multi-page PDF. I need to place a UIImage underneath the text that is rendered in the PDF. Here's what I have so far:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

    pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    NSInteger currentPage = 0;
    BOOL done = NO;

    do {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

        currentPage++;
        [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

        [self drawHeader];

        currentRange = [self renderPage:currentPage withTextRange:currentRange andFramesetter:framesetter];

        // If we're at the end of the text, exit the loop.
        if (currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength((CFAttributedStringRef)currentText))
            done = YES;
    }

    while (!done);
```

Then, I add an image in a separate PDF page:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    currentPage++;
    [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

    [self drawHeader];

    [self drawImages];
    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

However, if there is very little text on the PDF that is created, there will be a lot of unfilled white space. I need to place the image at the bottom of the current PDF if there is space, and create a new PDF if not. So, I need to check for a "y" position of the text.

How would I do that?

Comment: Just check the current "y" position within the page. Compare this with the image height and the page size. If the image fits, don't start a new page.

Comment: @rmaddy - That makes sense, but I'm using Core Text, per Apple Documentation. What could I check for "y" position?